# shift and rotation in matlab for handwritten digits

Tags: matlab, digit

Suppose we have number five from handwritten digit dataset. I want to rotate it 30 degrees (counter clockwise) then shift it 10 pixels vertical and horizontal. How should I do it?

Comment: Do you have the image processing toolbox? Does this matter what the image is of? Just use `imrotate`. Translation is absolutely trivial. If you don't have the toolbox then use this off the FEX: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27300-image-rotate-scale-and-translate

Comment: @Dan: It's not an image, it's a matrix.

Comment: You've described an image. If it isn't then please supply example data. If you just want to rotate a single vector then just multiply it by a rotation matrix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let I be your image.

```
%I = Input image;
J = imrotate(I,30); %To rotate
JS = [zeros(size(J,1),10), J]; %To shift 10pix horizontally 

figure,imshow(I)
figure,imshow(J)
figure,imshow(JS)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't have an image, the number in that dataset are vectors.

Comment: Image can be read as a matrix in Matlab. You can use matrix as image and vice-versa. Read up once.